# Converting text file into multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, file, multidimensional-array

I tried to write a php code that would read a text file, convert it into a multidimensional array.
My text looks like:

```
Random Header 1
1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3
...........
...........

Random Header Title 2
1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3
...........
...........
and the random header and lists
```

And now, I want to convert the above text into array that looks,

```
Array
(
    [Random Header 1] => Array
        (
           [0] => "1. List item 1",
           [1] => "2. List item 2",
           [2] => "3. List item 3"
     ),
     [Random Header Title 2] => Array
        (
           [0] => "1. List item 1",
           [1] => "2. List item 2",
           [2] => "3. List item 3"
     )
)
```

Notice that the headers begins with a string, and list items start with number.
I used php's file() function to read, I have a hard time converting into the way I wanted.

Comment: `Solution please!!` it's not working like that. First, show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Wheres the code? If you have use the `file()` function

Comment: I read a txt file named "text.txt" using php read function. I used foreach to loop through each line, I explode each line by space, to differentiate between header and list items that followed. Now, I needed a solution to form array shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) as you already did and loop through each line and check with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) if the first character of the line is a non-digit character (`\D` -> `[^0-9]`). If yes use it as key until you hit the next line with a non-digit character at the start.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("text.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $arr = [];
    $header = FALSE;

    foreach($lines as $line){
        if(preg_match("/^\D/", $line))
            $header = $line;
        if($header != $line)
            $arr[$header][] = $line;
    }

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [Random Header 1] => Array
        (
           [0] => 1. List item 1
           [1] => 2. List item 2
           [2] => 3. List item 3
     )
     [Random Header Title 2] => Array
        (
           [0] => 1. List item 1
           [1] => 2. List item 2
           [2] => 3. List item 3
     )
)
```

Comment: I'm new here, I tried to vote but I could not. It solves my problems. Thanks, you're the best @rizier123

Comment: @Lian You're welcome. Have a nice day :) (If you are new here, you can take a quick tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour to get an overview of this site)